# oozie fs action. copy command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, file-copying

I need to copy a directory from one hdfs-path to another one. However, I run into the absence of `copy` command in Oozie framework:

```
<action name="SOME_ACTION">
    <fs>
        <copy source='/foo/src_dir' target='/bar/dest_dir'  />
    </fs>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
</action>
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a `copy` command in `fs` action. That's the error, I have got:

> OozieClientException: org.apache.oozie.DagEngineException: E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'copy'. One of '{"uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":delete, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":mkdir, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":move, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":chmod, "uri:oozie:workflow:0.4":touchz}' is expected.

Why is `copy` command is absent and what is the canonical way copying hdfs directories in Oozie framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no copy in FS action. You can use the DistCp action to achieve this: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/DG_DistCpActionExtension.html